# Finding the upper bound of a function

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o

Example-3 Find upper bound for f(n) = n^4 + 100n^2 + 50

Solution: n^4 + 100n^2 + 50 ≤ 2n^4, for all n ≥ 11
∴ n^4 + 100n^2 + 50 = O(n^4 ) with c = 2 and n0 = 11

In the above question the solution says n>11 and n-nought is 11.
can anybody explain why is it 11?
for reference - this is a problem from the Data Structures and Algorithms Made Easy by Narasimha Karumanchi

Comment: Please instead of posting a picture of the text, write it in the question

Comment: this looks like homework help to me. not good.

Comment: @Jay No, this was a genuine search to understand a problem, if it was a homework why would i post the solution along.

Comment: false positive then :) we have so many people asking for homework help...the good ones get blamed like now. my apologies.

Answer (score 1):

`f(n) = n^4 + 100n^2 + 50`

Intuitively, `n^4` grows very fast; `n^2` grows less fast than `n^4`; and `50` doesn't grow at all.

However, for small values of `n`, `n^4 < 50`; additionally, the `n^2` term has a factor 100 in front of it. Because of this factor, for small values of `n`, n^4 < 100 n^2.

But because we have the intuition that `n^4` grows much faster than `n^2`, we expect that, for n big enough, `100 n^2 + 50 < n^4`.

In order to assert and prove this claim, we need to be more precise on what "for n big enough" means. Your textbook found an exact value; and they claimed: for n ≥ 11, `100 n^2 + 50 < n^4`.

How did they find that? Maybe they solved the inequality for `n`. Or maybe they just intuited it by noticing that:

```
100 n^2 = 10 * 10 * n * n`
    n^4 =  n * n  * n * n
```

Thus `n^4` is going to be the bigger of the two as soon as n is bigger than 10.

In conclusion: as soon as n ≥ 11, `f(n) < 2 n^4`. Thus, f(n) satisfies the textbook definition for `f(n) = O(n^4)`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't say that `n>11` it says that `n4 + 100n2 + 50 ≤ 2n4`, for all `n ≥ 11`.

Is it true? You can substitute `n` for `11` in the formula and check it yourself.

How was `11` obtained? By solving the inequality.

Answer (score 0):

It is not finding an upper bound for a function. It is an asymptotic analysis of a function with big-O notation. Hence, the constant `c = 11` does not matter for the analysis, and if you can show the inequality is valid for all `n` greater than any constant, for instance `c = 100`, that will be accepted. By the way, you can show that it is true for all `n > 11` by the mathematical induction.

Comment: Thank you but i don't completely understand because i'm new to this concept, Is it possible to recommend some source where i can get a clearer picture.

Comment: @PreethiNaidu many sources. You can start with "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis"